# php exec on java jar file output is empty array

Tags: java, php, macos, xampp

I got a new mac and installed the same xampp web server as my old one.
Everything has been fine except when I call a java file :

```
$str_exec = "java  -jar HelloWorld.jar";
exec($str_exec, $output,$result);
```

`$output` is now an empty `array()`, and `$result = 5`

I've tried absolute paths, permissions on everything, changing the user and group in https.conf (none of which I had to do before!)

I swear nothing has changed except I'm now using a macbook pro instead of an air.  The files have always matched our main server files.  The only thing appearing in the error log is:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
```

Help please!!  I've gone through all the similar threads to this issue on here and can't find anything on the internet anywhere!  Gnh

Comment: I'm having the same problem running exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/file.php"). I get a result of 5 and it doesn't run. I've tried so many things and still beating my head against the wall. Also using XAMPP for PHP 5.3 on macbook air.

Comment: ok, it appears that xampp sets DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib" which can cause lots of problems. still haven't figured out how to fix it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Don't use the solution below. It will eventually break, as expected. Mine finally broke, throwing dyld errors when I tried to start the apache server. It wouldn't start at all. No idea why it worked before and doesn't now, but it doesn't matter. Just ditch XAMPP, and follow these instructions to spin up your own stack: http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/

Good luck!

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**
Ok, I've got a working solution, although I know that it's not the safest by a long shot.

Here's what's up:
`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a var that modifies the way that the dynamic linking library looks for libs. Apparently many developers think that your software should not use this var. XAMPP does.

According to one solution, you can simply edit out the lines that include this file. (http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/support/PDFlib-in-PHP-HowTo.pdf).
Open `xamppfiles/bin/envvars` with an editor and remove the lines that set and export `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Then restart apache.

However, this did not work for me. I also tried the same in a file called `xamppfiles/bin/envvars-std`. Still didn't work. It may be worth a try though.

The problem is that the XAMPP library conflicts with the mac osx library. So I just (effectively) deleted the XAMPP library. Of course that broke another library, but I continued on deleting the (hopefully redundant) XAMPP libs until it worked. Here's what I had to do:

`XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib% sudo mv libjpeg.dylib _changed_libjpeg.dylib
XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib% sudo mv libtiff.dylib _changed_libtiff.dylib
XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib% sudo mv libpng.dylib _changed_libpng.dylib
XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib% sudo mv libiconv.2.dylib _changed_libiconv.2.dylib
XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib% sudo mv libexslt.0.dylib _changed_libexslt.0.dylib
XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib% sudo mv libxml2.2.dylib _changed_libxml2.2.dylib
XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib% sudo mv libxslt.1.dylib _changed_libxslt.1.dylib`

After I moved each library to a name where it couldn't find it, I reran the script. It would error on another lib, and I would move it. After a few of these, it stopped. Everything still seems to be working fine in my XAMPP and Apache deployments.

And more importantly, I can now run `exec("/usr/bin/php -v");` successfully!

HTH

Comment: Well done Ken!  I hope this helps others.  I ran out of time and just scrapped xampp and learned how to build the web server from scratch on the mac.  Took a few hours, but it works wonderfully and with no bloating!

Comment: yeah, i think ditching xampp is probably the better solution

Comment: I put to run this answer before call exec. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941078/ffmpeg-and-php-on-mac-doest-work