# FFMPEG and PHP on mac does`t work

Tags: php, macos, ffmpeg, xampp, exec

I need your help. Currently I use Mac OS X 10.9.4 and xampp apache 1.8.3-3. I need to use ffmpeg (version 3.2) to convert video files via php `exec()` but I cannot make it work. I did some testing running the terminal command line and the system operates normally. Only in php it doesn't work. 
ffmpeg was compiled and installed through the brew.

I ran the following test:

```
exec("/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.3/bin/ffmpeg -i /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/teste/trailer.mp4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/teste/trailer2.flv 2>&1", $o, $v);
var_dump($o);
var_dump($v);
```

and got the following:

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> string(51) "dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart" 
    [1]=> string(82) "Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO" 
    [2]=> string(63) "Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libJPEG.dylib" 
    [3]=> string(67) " in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO" } int(133)
```

Comment: Are you able to run ffmpeg from the command line as **the user the webserver is running as**? Your environment and the webserver's might easily be completely different.

Comment: Get another FFmpeg binary.

Answer (score 8):

problem is linked to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH being set to xampp libraries folder

try unsetting this before exec
any one of these before exec will work

```
exec('unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ;');
putenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH');
putenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin');
```

Comment: I got here twice. I was looking for a final solution. I tried change `xamppfiles/bin/envvars` to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/bin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib"` but it doesn't work. It works only if I change to `/usr/bin` but I think something can stop working without xampp lib.